# How to run oozie workflows faster

Tags: hadoop

So I have a large oozie workflow comprising somewhere of 300 actions, out of which there are few shells actions, sqoops, lot of hives and map-reduces. There are subworkflows as well.
I have a cluster of X machines, where each machine is having decent RAM and disk space.

The time taken by the total job in production is fine, however for development purposes where I have limited data for testing, the job still takes time on magnitude of hours.

I understand that even forking of one JVM takes about 1 to 3 seconds and this alone will make my job take 1 hour (considering 4MR jobs taken per action on an average) 
However since I know my data is small in development, I would like to make the execution much faster.

I think I should be able to run the entire oozie workflow on a single machine (1 out of those X) and be done with the job in a few minutes -

One of the alternatives I know is to run uber tasks - which I am currently exploring. However it seems it will only run the MR jobs of same hadoop job in the same JVM. 
So if a hive query fires 4 MR jobs, I'll still be needing 4 JVMs.

Is it possible to reuse JVMs across MR jobs?

Any other suggestions on faster runtimes for small amount of data will be helpful.

Thanks.